Are such positive symmetric matrices positive-definite?
Consider a matrix $ A = (a_{i,j}) \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) $ with the following properties for all indices $ i, j $:

$ a_{i,j} > 0 $ (meaning $ A $ is a positive matrix),
$ a_{i,j} = a_{j,i} $ (meaning $ A $ is symmetric),
$ a_{i,j} \leq \min(a_{i,i}, a_{j,j})/2 $, if $i \neq j$.

Question: Is a matrix $ A $ with these properties also positive-definite? In other words, are all its eigenvalues positive?
For the case when $ n = 2 $, it suffices to verify that the determinant of $ A $ is positive, which is indeed true because $ a_{1,2} < \min(a_{1,1}, a_{2,2}) $, whereas $\det(A) = a_{1,1}a_{2,2} - a_{1,2}^2$.
It is important to note that a weaker third condition as $ a_{i,j} < \min(a_{i,i}, a_{j,j}) $ (if $i \neq j$) is insufficient for $ n = 3 $. Here is a counterexample:
sage: M
[5 1 4]
[1 5 4]
[4 4 5]
sage: M.eigenvalues()
[4, -0.1789083458002736?, 11.17890834580028?]

However, with the third assumption $ a_{i,j} \le \min(a_{i,i}, a_{j,j})/2 $ (if $i \neq j$), no counterexample exists for $ n=3 $ when $ 1 \le a_{i,j} < 20 $ and all $ a_{i,j} $ are integers:
sage: for x11 in range(1,20):
....:     for x22 in range(1,20):
....:         for x33 in range(1,20):
....:             for x12 in range(1,1+int(min(x11,x22)/2)):
....:                 for x13 in range(1,int(min(x11,x33)/2)):
....:                     for x23 in range(1,int(min(x22,x33)/2)):
....:                         M=matrix([[x11, x12, x13],[x12,x22,x23],[x13,x23,x33]])
....:                         E=M.eigenvalues()
....:                         for x in E:
....:                             if x<=0:
....:                                 print(M,E)
sage:

Therefore, it is likely true for $n=3$. Additionally, there is no counterexample for $n=4 $ when $1 \le a_{i,j} \le 8$ and all $a_{i,j}$ are integers:
sage: def check(n):
....:     for x11 in range(1,n+1):
....:         for x22 in range(1,n+1):
....:             for x33 in range(1,n+1):
....:                 for x44 in range(1,n+1):
....:                     for x12 in range(1,1+int(min(x11,x22)/2)):
....:                         for x13 in range(1,1+int(min(x11,x33)/2)):
....:                             for x14 in range(1,1+int(min(x11,x44)/2)):
....:                                 for x23 in range(1,1+int(min(x22,x33)/2)):
....:                                     for x24 in range(1,1+int(min(x22,x44)/2)):
....:                                         for x34 in range(1,1+int(min(x33,x44)/2)):
....:                                             M=matrix([[x11,x12,x13,x14],[x12,x22,x23,x24],[x13,x23,x33,x34],[x14,x24,x34,x44]])
....:                                             E=M.eigenvalues()
....:                                             for x in E:
....:                                                 if x<=0:
....:                                                     print(M,E)
sage: %time check(8)
CPU times: user 6min 42s, sys: 214 ms, total: 6min 42s
Wall time: 6min 43s


@MartinR: But all the entries cannot be identical because $a_{i,j} \leq \min(a_{i,i}, a_{j,j})/2$ (if $i \neq j$) and $a_{i,j}>0$ for all $i,j$ implies that $a_{i,j} < \min(a_{i,i}, a_{j,j})$ (if $i \neq j$). Do you agree?

Yes of course, my fault.

It is true for $n \le 3$, and I assume that it is wrong for all $n \ge 4$.

The statement is not true. For a counterexample let $A$ be the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & \varepsilon & \varepsilon & 1 & 1 \\
\varepsilon & 2 & \varepsilon & 1 & 1 \\
\varepsilon & \varepsilon & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & \varepsilon \\
1 & 1 & 1 & \varepsilon & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It fulfills all assumptions as long as $0 < \varepsilon \leq 1$. Now consider the vector $v^\mathrm{T} = (1,1,1,-1,-1)$. Then we can calculate
$$
v^\mathrm{T}Av = (1,1,1,-1,-1)
\begin{pmatrix}
2\varepsilon \\ 2\varepsilon \\ 2\varepsilon \\ 1 - \varepsilon \\ 1 - \varepsilon 
\end{pmatrix}
= -2 + 8\varepsilon.
$$
This is negative for $\varepsilon < \frac14$. For a positive definite matrix this number is positive, though.
